# IBM DOORS DXL Link report

Tags: websphere, analysis, wizard, ibm-doors

Using DOORS 9.6 I need a Link report similar to the Analysis Wizard reports except:: I want a single line presenting the links from the initial node down to the leaf node. If A has links to B,C and then B has a link to D..
I would like to see the results of an Analysis Wizard with a display like this:
A->B->D  
A->C

The initial node would simply be the current module

Comment: the script would be based on the analysis Wizard with recursive analysis - I guess that instead of several `display`s, you will have to collect the information in a string variable or elsewhere. What have you tried to achieve - is there any specific programming problem we can help you with?

Comment: Not at this time, ty Mike